# pythonic way to write the following code

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How can I write the following code in a more python-ic way ?

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
list_2 = [2,4]
list_index = 0
list_3 = [0 for i in range(len(list_1)+len(list_2))]
for index in range(6):
      if index in list_2:
           list_3[index] = -1
      else:
           list_3[index] = list_1[list_index]
           list_index += 1
```

So the list_3 will contain = [1,2,-1,3,4,-1]

Comment: Please post working code

Comment: Here is the working code.

Comment: Please help me out. And please do not downvote

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is what you are looking for:

```
values = [2,5,8,3,5,7]
indexes = [0,3,5]

result = []
for i,v in enumerate(values):
    if i in indexes:
        result.append(-1)
        result.append(v)
    else:
        result.append(v)

print(result)
```

I am not sure about the exact logic expected, but this might be a good start.

Comment: This only extracts the elements required at particular index. I want to insert elements into a new list alongwith -1 at the required indices in the second list specified . The output according to my logic should be [-1,2,5,-1,8,-1,3,5,7]

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are some things you are doing wrong:

```
list_3 = [0 for i in range(len(list_1)+len(list_2))]
```

Is better written as

```
list_3 = [0] * (len(list_1)+len(list_2))
```

In general I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with your code. It seems very complicated for what it does.